# EF 6.1 Code First - the number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6.1

I am running into the following error while trying to migrate a database in Entity Framework.

The specified association foreign key columns 'question_set_id' are invalid. The number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns.

I dropped the original primary key QuestionSetId and created a composite key relationship. The columns in the composite key relationship also map to foreign keys. I'm not sure what the issue is.

Here is the associated entity.

```
public class QuestionSet
{
    [Key, Column(Order = 1)]
    public long TitleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("TitleId")]
    public virtual Title Title { get; set; }

    [Key, Column(Order = 0)]
    public long ReviewCycleId { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey("ReviewCycleId")]
    public virtual ReviewCycle ReviewCycle { get; set; }

    public virtual List<Question> Questions { get; set; }
}
```

The DbContext has:

```
    modelBuilder.Entity<QuestionSet>()
            .HasMany(c => c.Questions)
            .WithMany(c => c.QuestionSets)
                .Map(x => x.ToTable("QUESTION_SET_QUESTION")
                    .MapLeftKey("question_set_id")
                    .MapRightKey("question_id"))
        ;
```

Comment: It seems to me that the error is generated from the `Question` Entity. This Entity should have a composite foreign key to `QuestionSet`. It seems that `Question` has question_set_id as the foreign key for its `QuestionSet`though.

Comment: Thanks I'll look into that possibility. I've discovered some other issues due the the fact that it is a many to many relationship. I'll edit my post with more information after I look into it further.

Comment: There you have it: `QuestionSet` has a composite primary key and you are specifying a single foreign key in your fluent API code for the Question_Set_Question junction table.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `QuestionSet` has two keys, but the `MapLeftKey` of `QuestionSet` only spefified one key.

```
MapLeftKey("question_set_id")
```

Replace it with something like this:

```
MapLeftKey(new []{ "question_set_review_cycle_id", "question_set_title_id" })
```

The first key is `ReviewCycleId` (Column's Order 0), the second key is `TitleId` (Column's Order 1).

It should fix the problem, unless the `Question` also has two keys.

Comment: Thank you this was helpful and did in fact fix the problem!