# ASP.NET Identity Creating ApplicationUser_Id Foreign Key

Tags: c#, asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am having issues with ASP.NET Identity creating an incorrect table relationship between my Role and UserAcccount table

Here is my OnModelCreating:

```
    protected override void OnModelCreating(DbModelBuilder modelBuilder)
    {
        base.OnModelCreating(modelBuilder);

        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserClaim>().ToTable("UserClaim").ToTable("UserClaim").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserClaimID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserRole>().ToTable("UserRole");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityUserLogin>().ToTable("UserLogin");
        modelBuilder.Entity<IdentityRole>().ToTable("Role").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("RoleID");
        modelBuilder.Entity<ApplicationUser>().ToTable("UserAccount").ToTable("UserAccount").Property(p => p.Id).HasColumnName("UserID");
    }
```

Here is the resulting migration:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Role",
            c => new
                {
                    RoleID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    ApplicationUser_Id = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.RoleID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserAccount", t => t.ApplicationUser_Id)
            .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex")
            .Index(t => t.ApplicationUser_Id);
```

Here is what I want to see:

```
        CreateTable(
            "dbo.Role",
            c => new
                {
                    RoleID = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    Name = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 256),
                    Description = c.String(),
                    Discriminator = c.String(nullable: false, maxLength: 128),
                    UserID = c.String(maxLength: 128),
                })
            .PrimaryKey(t => t.RoleID)
            .ForeignKey("dbo.UserAccount", t => t.UserID)
            .Index(t => t.Name, unique: true, name: "RoleNameIndex")
            .Index(t => t.UserID);
```

I have referenced several other StackOverflow posts and other resources that almost solve my problem, but not quite:
[EF 6.1 Code First - the number of columns specified must match the number of primary key columns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25729984/ef-6-1-code-first-the-number-of-columns-specified-must-match-the-number-of-pri), [MapKey vs HasForeignKey Difference - Fluent Api](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15595818/mapkey-vs-hasforeignkey-difference-fluent-api), https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/hh134698.aspx.

Comment: Why don't you use IdentityDbContext ?

Comment: OnModelCreating is a method in my ApplicationDbContext class that overrides IdentityDbContext.

Comment: Hum strange when I make a sample, all this code is not here. This is not a part of the IdentityDbContext to take care of all of it ?